# Jacobian of matrix product in SU(n)

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds

I need to compute the determinant of the jacobian matrix of the function $f: SO(n)\times SO(n) \rightarrow SO(n)\times SO(n)$ given by $f(P,V) = (PV, P^TV)$. I've found the jacobian if we extend $f$ to the whole of $M(n)$, but I'm not sure how to find the jacobian of the restricted map.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each small neighbourhood of $(P,V)\in SO(n,\mathbb{R})\times SO(n,\mathbb{R})$, let us represent each point in the neighbourhood by $(e^XP, e^YV)$ for some skew symmetric matrices $X$ and $Y$. Then $(e^XP, e^YV)-(P,V)=(XP,YV)+o(\sqrt{\|XP\|_F^2+\|YV\|_F^2})$ (where $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the Frobenius norm) and
\begin{align*}
&\left(e^XPe^YV,\ (e^XP)^T e^YV\right) - \left(PV,\ P^T V\right)\\
=&\left( (e^X Pe^YP^T)PV,\ \left(P^Te^{-X} e^YP\right)P^TV\right)  - \left(PV,\ P^T V\right)\\
=&\left((X + PYP^T)PV,\ \left(-P^TXP+P^TYP\right)P^TV\right)+o(\sqrt{\|XP\|_F^2+\|YV\|_F^2}).
\end{align*}
Therefore, the derivative of $f$ at $(P,V)$ is the linear operator $Df(P,V):\mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb{R})P\times \mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb{R})V\to\mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb{R})PV\times \mathfrak{so}(n,\mathbb{R})P^TV$ defined by
$$
(XP,YP)\mapsto\left((X + PYP^T)PV,\ \left(-P^TXP+P^TYP\right)P^TV\right).
$$
That is, $Df(P,V)=h\circ g\circ s$ where
\begin{align*}
s(XP,YP)&=(X,Y),\\
g(X,Y)=(Z,W)&=\left(X + PYP^T,\ -P^TXP+P^TYP\right),\\
h(Z,W)&=\left(ZPV,\ WP^TV\right)
\end{align*}
and $\det Df(P,V)=\det(h)\det(g)\det(s)$. Using Kronecker product, we can express $s$ and $g$ as
\begin{align*}
g\left(\mathrm{vec}(X,Y)\right) = \pmatrix{I\otimes I& P\otimes P\\ -P^T\otimes P^T&P^T\otimes P^T}\mathrm{vec}(X,Y).
\end{align*}
Therefore $\det(g)=\det\left((I\otimes I)(P^T\otimes P^T) - (P\otimes P)(P^T\otimes P^T)\right)=\det(P\otimes P + I_{n^2})$. Similarly, since $\det(P)=\det(V)=1$, we have $\det(h)=\det(s)=1$. Hence
$$\det Df(P,V)=\det(P\otimes P+I_{n^2}).$$

---

Of course, you may also express each point in a small neighbourhood by $(Pe^X,Ve^Y)$. In this case, we obtain
\begin{align*}
&\left(Pe^X Ve^Y,\ (Pe^X)^T Ve^Y\right) - \left(PV,\ P^T V\right)\\
=&\left(PV (V^Te^X Ve^Y),\ P^TV \left((P^T V)^T e^{-X} (P^T V)e^Y\right)\right)  - \left(PV,\ P^T V\right)\\
=&\left(PV (V^T X V + Y),\ P^TV \left(-(P^T V)^T X (P^T V) + Y\right)\right)+o(\sqrt{\|X\|_F^2+\|Y\|_F^2}).
\end{align*}
and hence $Df(P,V)$ is given by
$$
(PX,VY)\mapsto\left(PV (V^T X V + Y),\ P^TV \left(-(P^T V)^T X (P^T V) + Y\right)\right).
$$
Again, $\det Df(P,V)=\det(P\otimes P+I_{n^2})$.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Comment: Working through your answer here, and as far as I understand it, you find the differential by finding the linear part of $f(P,V) + \epsilon)$, where $(X,Y)$ take the part of $\epsilon$, since for small $X,Y$, the matrices $P,V$ will remain orthogonal, am I correct? What I don't quite grasp is, why do you use $e^X$, and not $e^{P^TX}$, as $Pe^X \approx P + PX$ and not what I would think you'd want, $P + X$? Anything obvious I've missed?

Comment: Is the reason this works because the $det V = det P = 1$, so multiplying $X$ with $P$ and $Y$ with $V$ has $det$ 1? Is this also why $PV$ and $P^TV$ is dropped from the formula of g? If so, I think I got it :)

Comment: @Greebo I made a mistake. I simply *forgot* that $dP=PX$ rather than $X$. However, since $\det P=1$, it turns out that this mistake does not matter. I also mistook $n=3$ when I first answered this question. I hope the answer is now clear enough.

Comment: It's clearer now, thanks a lot!